# Re-open the DropDown of an AutoCompleteBox in Silverlight when a user presses Enter

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, autocomplete

If a user types a few characters into an AutoCompleteBox, the DropDown is displayed as expected.

If the user then clicks elsewhere on the page, this removes the focus from the AutoCompleteBox, and the DropDown disappears... also as expected.

However, if a user then returns focus to the AutoCompleteBox, and wants to redisplay the DropDown, filtering on the characters already there, the instinct seems to be to press the Enter key to re-filter/re-display the results.  This, however, does not happen.

I've managed to capture the Enter key event (must use KeyUp instead of KeyDown), but I'm not sure how to make the DropDown re-appear at that point.  Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign `true` to the `IsDropDownOpen` property:-

```
myACB.IsDropDownOpen = true;
```